# Sharing and permission

Tags: sharing, permission, file

How can I set sharing and permission on Mac os x to be -rwx for all?
When I create file or folder it is *read and write* for me but for all others it is *Read only*. If there is more files just copied from USB to some unlocked folder, automatical it is *read only* for all other users. Because we share files it is annoying. So please help.

Comment: Please clarify. Do you mean other users on same computer?

Comment: Assuming local shares try `chmod ugo+rwx <name of file>`. chmod can effect multiple files with options, check `man chmod` for more information.

Answer (score 2):

Set your umask to 000 and reboot, then all files will save with full permissions for everyone. Here is the documentation http://support.apple.com/kb/ht2202